# HBase as Input -> unable to balance load over available map tasks

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I want each hadoop mapper to process a separate portion of data at a M/R job and I would like to test on a pseudo-distributed (single-node) setup the case where many mappers would  be necessary to exist as a result of a bigger input-data size. Given the size of my current input and the standalone mode I am experimenting on, I can only see 1 map task.

My input comes from an hbase table and I thought that the number of regions per hbase table is equal to the number of mappers used to process the table's data.

So, as to reproduce a case where many mappers would process the input data, I predefined regions of table through shell like this :

create 't1', 'f1', {NUMREGIONS => 4, SPLITALGO => 'HexStringSplit'}

or setting 'UniformSplit' as SPLITALGO, but even if mappers indeed **increase** to the specified number of regions (after importing data to the respective table), all the input data (at a subsequent test job where I try to read from this table) pass through **only one** mapper - with the others processing none of the input rows.

I work on a pseudo-distributed (single-node) setup and I really don't know how to solve this. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you scanning the entire table or just a section of it?  If you are scanning a section of the table, then that might be the cause of your problem as your data source isn't big enough to trigger multiple mappers.

You can try to decrease the region size in your hbase-size.xml configuration and restart hbase to achieve the desired effect.

Lastly, in your mapred-site.xml configuration, how many mapper slots do you have?  If it is just 1, this will not limit the number of map jobs, but it will limit the number of map jobs that can be run at a time on that server.

Other than that, I don't think you have much control over specifying the number of mappers per job- not like you do with the number of reducers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time - I am not using a portion of the dataset, but you 're right, I will try experimenting with a bigger one, as well as working on a real cluster soon, hoping to solve the load balancing issue, instead of trying to debug an unrealistic situation on a standalone mode.

Comment: You can also do a region split on your table manually through the command line or using the HBase web interface.  THat might do it as well.

Comment: But, I have already done this through this command:

create 't1', 'f1', {NUMREGIONS => 4, SPLITALGO => 'HexStringSplit'}

and my problem was that all load went through 1 of the 4 created map tasks.. Excuse me if I didn't understand the remark.

Comment: You can manually force a split of an individual region in hbase, this will create more regions and i think more mappers.  You can do the split with the commandline, the hbase web interface, or through code e.g. using the java api.